# Python3 reduce() function alternative using loop instead of using from functools import reduce

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a python2 code that I used before but I would like replace reduce by a loop. How can I rewrite this part `prod = reduce(lambda a, b: a * b, n)` function below?

```
def chineeseRemainder(n, a):
    sum = 0
    prod = reduce(lambda a, b: a * b, n)

    for n_i, a_i in zip(n, a):
        p = prod // n_i
        sum += a_i * Get_Multi_Inv(p, n_i) * p
    return sum % prod
```

Comment: I am trying not to import the functools library

Comment: You can also see a possible [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) implementation in the docs. It's probably a bit more cautious than your implementation would need to be, but it will give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was looking at it but I was able to  understand what to use iterable, initializer=None based on my function above.. I guess, i can have function as lambda a,b:a*b but what to putt for iterable, initializer=None..

Comment: def reduce(lambda a,b:a*b, n, initializer=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    if initializer is None:
        value = next(it)
    else:
        value = initializer
    for element in it:
        value = function(value, element)
    return value

Comment: Does glitches solution not answer your question?

Comment: I figure it out using the link provided. Thanks

Comment: cool but bear in mind that if you were just gong to copy the code from functools then you may as well just use functools. As long as you really understand what that code is doing then its all good.

Answer (score 1):

In general for a `reduce()` without a starting value, you can use `iter` and `next` to convert it to a for loop. This combination lets you use the first element of the iterable as the starting accumulator value, and loop over the rest.

```
iterator = iter(n)
prod = next(iterator)
for x in iterator:
    prod *= x
```

But in the specific case of multiplication, we know the identity element is `1`, so we can use that as the starting value and multiply the whole iterable.

```
prod = 1
for x in n:
    prod *= x
```

Not all functions will have an identity like this, but many do, like `0` for `+` and `math.inf` for `min()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can also add import

```
from functools import reduce
```

Answer (score 1):

I have it working.

```
def reduce(function, iterable, initializer=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    if initializer is None:
        value = next(it)
    else:
        value = initializer
    for element in it:
        value = function(value, element)
    return value
```

and I called it the function above with

```
prod = reduce(function1, n)
```

Comment: If you're going to make a generic `reduce` function, why not use the one builtin? You can use `six` as a compatibility layer.  The benefit of not using reduce is readability (and possibly one less func call); this solution eschews both of those benefits.